# Basic Matrix calculations

Tags: matrices

I'm trying to answer these two questions about matrix.

I/ Let $$U=\begin{bmatrix}a & 1 \\0 & b \end{bmatrix}$$ Compute $$U^n$$

I find $$U^2=\begin{bmatrix}a^2 & a+b \\0 & b^2 \end{bmatrix}  U^3=\begin{bmatrix}a^3 & a^2+b(a+b)\\0 & b^3 \end{bmatrix}  U^4=\begin{bmatrix}a^4 & a^3+(a^2+b(a+b))b\\0 & b^4 \end{bmatrix}$$

So $$U^n=\begin{bmatrix}a^n & ?\\0 & b^n \end{bmatrix}$$ I do not find the $$a_{1,2}$$ coefficient, I think $$a^{n-1}+b(a+b)^{n-2}$$ but it does not work for every power.

2)Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ Tell if the matrix B such as $$B \in \mathbb{M}_{2,3}(R)$$ such as $$AB=I_3$$ exists. Same thing with $$\mathbb{C}_{2,3}(R)$$ such as $$CA=I_2$$ I do not see how to answer...

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answer however I'm beggining in Maths and still haven't seen diagonalisation, for this exercize I have to deduce $$U^n$$ according to the other powers.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the pattern:
$$n=1 : 1 $$
$$n=2 : a+b$$
$$n=3 : a^2+ab+b^2$$
$$n=4 : a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3$$

We can arrive at the summation $$U^n_{1,2}=\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}a^{n+k-1}b^k$$

Now you can check by substituting $n=3$ or $n=4$ in the above, or by taking any suitable example matrix (as in the question).